# Windows Server 2008 Domain Controller Missing IUSR account

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, active-directory, iis-7

We have a Windows Server 2008 box running as a secondary domain controller, our primary domain controller is a Windows Server 2003 machine and both the domain and forest functional levels are set to 2003. We have subsequently installed IIS7 for some internal test projects, however when setting up the first site we discovered that the box seemed to be missing both the IUSR and IIS_IUSRS built-in accounts.  Obviously we need these accounts to set the permissions correctly for any web applications we choose to setup.

After some investigation, I discovered [this article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/946139), with an associated JScript file to run to resolve the issue, unfortunately after running the script and rebooting, the IUSR account is still missing.  (The IIS_IUSRS account has been restored)

Any ideas on how to resolve this would be much appreciated.

Comment: perhaps this should be moved to ServerFault?

Comment: There are no "primary" or "secondary" domain controllers in Active Directory-- only replicas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reverse-engineering the script provides some hints about what it does, but ultimately the behavior that it attempts to invoke occurs inside the "black box" of the Active Directory domain controller code itself, so troubleshooting it is going to be difficult (unless you've got source code access to AD... >smile<).

Essentially, the script prepares the domain for an [runSamUpgradeTasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd240061(PROT.13).aspx) call, then executes it. This involves appending a value to the otherWellKnownObjects attribute of the "CN=Server, CN=System. DC=domain..." object in the directory, then making an LDAP call to modify the runSamUpgradeTasks attribute. That's *supposed* to trigger the W2K8 domain controller to automatically create its default groups and users in the directory and, as such, cause the missing account and group to be created.

I'm a little dubious of the script because the runSamUpgradeTasks reference calls for the balue to be appended to otherWellKnownObjects attribute to end with "...:X", whereas the script doesn't do that. Even so, you indicate that the "IIS_IUSRS" group was created, so that means that, presumably, the W2K8 DC "got the message" and created groups.

This one is fairly perplexing, and I'd opt to go to Microsoft Product Support Services on it. You're not going to spend a *lot* of money, but given the strangeness of the behaviour you're seeing they're probably the best people on the planet to help you.